# How can I hold UpValues but evaluate other expressions?

Tags: programming, evaluation, variable-definitions, upvalues

Consider these definitions:

```
own = "OwnValue";
down[_] = "DownValue";
sub[_][_] = "SubValue";
N[n] = 3.14;
_[___, up, ___] ^= "UpValue";
```

The attribute `HoldAllComplete` holds an UpValue but it also holds the other Values as well.

Without advance knowledge of the symbol `up` how can I evaluate everything but the UpValue?

`Set` and related functions appear to have this evaluation property internally:

```
f[own, down[1], sub[1][2], N[n], up] = 1;

Definition[f]
```

> ```
> f["OwnValue", "DownValue", "SubValue", 3.14, up] = 1
> ```

---

The first idea that comes to mind is to test if a symbol has an UpValue and skip evaluation if it does, but this proves problematic.  First, a symbol can have both an OwnValue and an UpValue, and the OwnValue should be used if possible:

```
x[up3] ^= 2;
up3 = 1;

f[up3]
```

> ```
> f[1] (* desired output *)
> ```

Second, testing for an UpValue can be difficult:

```
_[___, up4, ___] ^= {};

UpValues[up4] === UpValues[Plus]
```

> True

---

To clarify, it is not my intent to return `f[. . ., up]` as output, which would require `Defer` or similar.  Rather I would like to handle the expression `f[. . ., up]` as an argument like `Set` does, or define a function `f[args___] := . . .` (with attribute `HoldAllComplete`) that returns e.g. `{"OwnValue", "DownValue", "SubValue", 3.14, HoldComplete[up]}`

How can this be achieved?

Comment: When you write `f[up]=1`, `up` appears at the second level.  This is the reason why the `UpValue` does not evaluate.  Consider `x=up` (which is `Set[x,up]`)---this evaluates to `"UpValue"` right away.  Now try `SetAttributes[fun, HoldAll]` and `fun[p[up]]`---this one does not evaluate because UpValues are evaluated only in the first level of held heads (just like `Unevaluated`, `Sequence`, etc.)

Comment: @Szabolcs believe it or not I know this. :^)  I guess I didn't formulate my question all that well.  Would you join me in Chat to work it out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does this work as you want to?

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldAllComplete];
{first, rest___} ^:= HoldComplete[rest]
f[args___] := {first, args}

f[own, down[1], sub[1][2], N[n], up]
```

> HoldComplete["OwnValue", "DownValue", "SubValue", 3.14, up]

Comment: Competing UpValues!  Brilliant.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand it correctly, the gist of your question is going from

```
HoldComplete[x, y, z, up]
```

to

```
HoldComplete[1, y^2, z, up]
```

assuming the following definitions:

```
_[___, up, ___] ^= "UpValueEvaluated"
x = 1
f[x_] := x^2
```

That is, evaluate everything inside the `HoldComplete` except the `UpValue`.  I managed to do this using the following construction:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[
 {RuleCondition},
 Attributes[RuleCondition] = {HoldAllComplete};
 Replace[HoldComplete[x, f[y], z, up], e_ :> RuleCondition[e], {1}]
]
```

The undocumented `RuleCondition` is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7679152/695132).  This construction should be able to emulate the behaviour of `Set`.

Comment: Intersting one...

Comment: @Rojo I'm still reading the other solutions.

Comment: +1, clever.  If desired, we can avoid using ``Internal`InheritedBlock`` by means of a helper identity function: `SetAttributes[hci, HoldAllComplete]; hci[x_] := x`.  Then we can write: `Replace[HoldComplete[x, f[y], z, up], e_ :> RuleCondition @ hci @ e, {1}]`.

Comment: @WReach & Szabolcs I don't understand how this works (both methods).  Please enlighten me!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Here's the key: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633236/replace-inside-held-expression/7679152#7679152  It's a way to evaluate any subexpression inside a held expression.  I take all elements of the `HoldComplete` and evaluate them one-by-one.  I need to take care on the way not to end up with `something[up]` where `something` doesn't have `HoldAllComplete` (this way the challenge).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `HoldAllComplete` suppresses the application of up-values.  That is one of main differences between it and `HoldAll`.  Combined with the held-evaluation trick, the desired behaviour is obtained -- at least for the sample cases.  Nested sequences and other less-frequent constructs may pose further problems, but it is a clever solution just the same.

Comment: I'm aware of `RuleCondition` though I don't claim to fully understand its internals.  I still however do not understand the *mechanism* by which this evaluates other things besides the UpValue.

Answer (score 5):

To answer my own question and further illustrate the kind of operation I am describing, here is a method using `Set` itself:

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldAllComplete]

f[args___] :=
  Module[{h},
    h[args] = 1;
    Level[DownValues@h, {4}, HoldComplete]
  ]

f[own, down[1], sub[1][2], N[n], up]
```

> ```
> HoldComplete["OwnValue", "DownValue", "SubValue", 3.14, up]
> ```