# TagSetDelayed on a function with a delayed value

Tags: function-construction, syntax

I'm trying to automatically optimize cases when the user evaluates `Length[returnsList[x_]]` to instead use `returnsLength`:

```
Clear[returnsList, returnsLength]
returnsList[a_] := ConstantArray[4,a]
returnsLength[a_] := a
returnsList /: Length[returnsList[a_]] := returnsLength[a]
```

That causes

> ConstantArray::ilsmn: Single or list of non-negative machine-sized integers expected at position 2 of ConstantArray[4,a_].
>
> TagSetDelayed::tagnf: Tag returnsList not found in Length[ConstantArray[4,a_]].

I'm surprised that `returnsList` is evaluating. I tried `SetAttributes[returnsList, HoldAll]`, but I get the same message (and I don't want to deal with Hold* unless I must).

The first example in ref/TagSetDelayed likewise breaks if I assign a value to `g`, `g[x_] := 2`, but this seems like the intended use case. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your goal is clear, but it contradicts with Mathematica evaluation order. The main problem is that `Length` evaluates its argument. Please check [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73008) question and especially Leonid's comments. You can use my answer with two `UpValue` definitions from there, but I don't recommend to do so.

```
Clear[returnsList, returnsLength]
Length[returnsList[a_]] ^:= returnsLength[a]
h_[x___, returnsList[a_], y___] ^:= h[x, ConstantArray[4, a], y]
returnsLength[a_] := a

x = returnsList[6]
(* {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4} *)

Length[returnsList[6]]
(* 6 *)

returnsList[6]
(* returnsList[6] *)
```

Instead, I propose to use dummy `length` definition with `HoldAll` attribute:

```
ClearAll[returnsList, length]
returnsList[a_] := ConstantArray[4, a]
SetAttributes[length, HoldAll];
length[returnsList[a_Integer]] := a
length[returnsList[a_List]] := First[a]
length[x_] := Length[x];

length[returnsList[6]]
(* 6 *)

length[returnsList[{2, 4}]]
(* 2 *)

length[returnsList[6]] // Trace
(* {length[returnsList[6]],6} *)
```

Another possibility is to build your own "object":

```
ClearAll[myList]
Normal@myList[a_] ^:= ConstantArray[4, a]
Length@myList[a_Integer] ^:= a
Length@myList[a_List] ^:= First@a

myList[6]
(* myList[6] *)

Normal@myList[6]
(* {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4} *)

Length@myList[6]
(* 6 *)
```

Comment: What do you think about using a more restrictive pattern, e.g., `returnsList[a_Integer] := ConstantArray[4, a]`?

Comment: Nevermind, I just realised this has the same flaw as m_goldberg's one!

Comment: @sebhofer I decided to be more general. Please check my small update.

Comment: I like both your solutions. I think the first one might be more appealing to the OP as it seems more transparent. I also like the `Normal`-form of `myList` a lot. I never thought about this!

Comment: @sebhofer Please check the output of `Quantity; Information@Quantity; ClearAttributes[Quantity, ReadProtected]; Information@Quantity` as an example :)

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific what you want me to look at, the output is kind of bit ;)

Comment: @sebhofer Of course, output is huge. You can see how many functions of `Quantity[...]` are defined in similar manner. Behavior of other internal structures like `SparseArray` and `SeriesData` is similar, but it is defined on low level.

Comment: Thanks. Using `length` would defeat the purpose because the user would have to know about `length`, whereas they could likewise know about `returnsLength` -- no longer an automagical optimization. I'm trying to understand the answer you linked to but I don't get what the second UpValue matches. Could you please show how that might be adapted to this case?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure you are doing anything wrong (i.e., perhaps this is a bug) but a little experimenting shows that your `TagSetDelayed` expression must be evaluated before `returnsList` has any down values. That is, the following sequence of evaluations succeeds.

```
Clear[returnsList, returnsLength]
returnsList /: Length[returnsList[a_]] := returnsLength[a]
returnsList[a_] := ConstantArray[4, a]
returnsLength[a_] := a
Length[returnsList[6]]
```

> `6`

Comment: Unfortunately, it evaluates `ConstantArray` inside.

Comment: @ybeltukov maybe your comment would be clearer with `Length[returnsList[6]] // Trace` :)

Answer (score 0):

Ah, quoting. How about:

```
returnsList /: Length[Unevaluated[returnsList[a_]]] := returnsLength[a]
```

Comment: `Length[returnsList[5]] // Trace`

Comment: As with @m_goldberg's answer, this avoids the messages but doesn't actually make use of `returnsLength`. :(