# Is it possible to change the order that symbol definitions are checked? (DownValues vs UpValues)

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, pattern-matching, argument-patterns

Suppose I have the function `f` with the following definition assigned to it:

```
f // ClearAll;
f // Attributes = { HoldAll };
f /: HoldPattern[ f[x_] + f[y_] ] := upvalue;
```

If I evaluate `f[x] + f[y]`, I get `upvalue` as expected. Now if I instead use the definitions:

```
f // ClearAll;
f // Attributes = { HoldAll };
f /: HoldPattern[ f[x_] + f[y_] ] := upvalue;
f[x_] := downvalue;
```

the last one will take precedence, so `f[x] + f[y]` gives `2 downvalue`. From a trace, it's pretty easy to see why this happens, since the second argument isn't seen until after the first has been evaluated:

```
(* In *)
Column[ Trace[ f[x] + f[y], TraceOriginal -> True ] ]

(* Out *)
f[x] + f[y]
{Plus}
{f[x], {f}, f[x], downvalue}
{f[y], {f}, f[y], downvalue}
downvalue + downvalue
2 downvalue
{Times}
{2}
{downvalue}
2 downvalue
```

However, I'd like to know if there's good way to prioritize the first definition so I get `upvalue` instead? A possible workaround would be to do something like this:

```
(* In *)
Hold[ f[x] + f[y] ] /. UpValues[f] /. DownValues[f] // ReleaseHold

(* Out *)
upvalue
```

but that's a pretty ugly solution. Anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: Related: [Using up-values and down-values](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73008/14303)

Comment: Also related: [(544)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/544/121), [(2793)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2793/121), [(8558)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8558/121), [(19067)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19067/121), [(76008)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76008/121)

Answer (score 10):

Without thinking about any consequences, one idea popped into my mind. First, your definitions for `f` with the `DownValues`. I made it a bit more interesting:

```
ClearAll[f];
f // Attributes = {HoldAll};
f /: HoldPattern[f[x_] + f[y_]] := upvaluesSeen[f[x], f[y]];
f[x_] := downvalue[x]
```

How about a small wrapper function that temporarily deletes all `DownValues` of `f`. With this, the `UpValues` can act and as soon as we leave the wrapper, we go back to normal. At this point, you should instantly think of `` Internal`InheritedBlock ``.

```
SetAttributes[prioritizeUpvalues, {HoldAll}];
prioritizeUpvalues[expr_, f_Symbol] := Internal`InheritedBlock[{f},
  DownValues[f] =.;
  expr
]
```

Now, here we go

```
prioritizeUpvalues[f[x] + f[y], f]
(* upvaluesSeen[downvalue[x], downvalue[y]] *)
```

or

```
prioritizeUpvalues[f[x]*f[y], f]
(* downvalue[x] downvalue[y] *)
```

or

```
f[3]
(* downvalue[3] *)
```

Answer (score 8):

Adapting Leonid's method for [How do you set attributes on SubValues?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/544/how-do-you-set-attributes-on-subvalues/545#545)

```
ClearAll[f, g];
SetAttributes[{f, g}, HoldAll];
g /: g[x_] + g[y_] := upvalue;
f[x_] := downvalue

f :=
 With[{stack = Stack[_] /. HoldPattern[f] :> g},
   With[{foo = Cases[stack, Alternatives @@ _ /@ First /@ UpValues @ g]},
     g /; foo =!= {}
   ] /; stack =!= {}
 ]
```

Now:

```
f[1]
f[2]
f[1] + f[2]
```

> ```
> downvalue
>
> downvalue
>
> upvalue
> ```

- See Leonid's caveats before applying this method widely
- Later I'll try to provide a metaprogramming wrapper for this as I did for [How can I overload a function with multiple bracket-slots so f[a][b] and f[a] can coexist?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76008/121)

Answer (score 4):

You can hide your workaround in `$Pre`:

```
SetAttributes[specialEvaluate, HoldAll]
specialEvaluate[expr_] := ReleaseHold[
  Hold[expr] /. UpValues[f]
  ]
$Pre = specialEvaluate;
```

And now:

```
f[1] + f[2]
(* Out: upvalue *)
```

Comment: A caveat: this only works on user input rather than expressions generated internally.