# How to deal with bad arguments when a function's UpValues is a pure-function?

Tags: programming, function-construction, warning-messages, upvalues

In practice, I needs to define the `UpValues` of a user-defined function. For instance, the operation of function like differential formula , expansion and so on.

Here, I will give a example that came from my answer. Please see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88861/checking-the-argument-of-user-defined-function-with-side-effect-method/89105#89105)

```
Bernstein::invidx = 
 "Index `1` should be a non-negative machine-sized integer betwwen `2` and `3`.";

SyntaxInformation[Bernstein] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_,_,_}};

SetAttributes[Bernstein, NumericFunction]
(*special cases*)
Bernstein[0, 0, u_?NumericQ] := 1
Bernstein[0, 0, u_Symbol] := 1

(*normal cases*)
Bernstein[deg_Integer?NonNegative, idx_Integer?NonNegative, u_?NumericQ] /;
  idx <= deg && 0 <= u <= 1 :=
 Binomial[deg, idx] u^idx (1 - u)^(deg - idx)

Bernstein[deg_Integer?NonNegative, idx_Integer?NonNegative, u_?NumericQ] /;
  idx <= deg && (u > 1 || u < 0) := 0
```

#### Throw the error-informations

```
Bernstein[deg_Integer?NonNegative, idx_Integer?NonNegative, u_] /;
  idx > deg && (Message[Bernstein::invidx, idx, 0, deg - 1]; False) := $Failed;

expr : Bernstein[deg_ /; ! (IntegerQ[deg] && NonNegative[deg]), idx_, u_] /;
 (Message[Bernstein::intnm, Unevaluated[expr], 1]; False) := $Failed;

expr : Bernstein[deg_, idx_ /; ! (IntegerQ[idx] && NonNegative[idx]), u_] /;
 (Message[Bernstein::intnm, Unevaluated[expr], 2]; False) := $Failed;

Bernstein[args___] /;
 ! ArgumentCountQ[Bernstein, Length[{args}], 3, 3] && False := $Failed;
```

**The derivatives of Bernstein basis**

```
Bernstein /: Derivative[0, 0, k_Integer?Positive][Bernstein] :=
 Function[{deg, idx, u},
  D[
   deg (Bernstein[deg - 1, idx - 1, u] - Bernstein[deg - 1, idx, u]),
   {u, k - 1}]
 ]
```

#### TEST

```
D[Bernstein[3, -2, x], x]
D[Bernstein[3, -2, x], {x, 2}]
```

[image]

#### Question

- How to deal with bad arguments when a function's `UpValues` is a pure-function? Namely, throw the error information and then return the symbol `$Failed`.

---

Although Mr.Wizard given me a solution that using `If[]`

```
func /: Derivative[0, 0, 1][func] :=
 Function[{n, i, x},
  If[MatchQ[n, _Integer?NonNegative] && MatchQ[i, _Integer?NonNegative] && i <= n,
   n (func[n - 1, i - 1, x] - func[n - 1, i, x]),
   Defer@func[n, i, x]
 ]
]
```

However, which leads to another issue.

[image]

In fact, the *built-in* `BSplineBasis[]` also ingnore this problem.

```
knots = {0, 0, 0, 0, 1/3, 2/3, 1, 1, 1, 1};
D[BSplineBasis[{3, knots}, 7, x], {x, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Somewhat related: [(8558)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8558/121).

Comment: I updated my answer with two minor changes that appear to address your new example.  Please let me know if and where this fails; I did not try to be exhaustive.

Answer (score 3):

This references [a past dialog](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85821/121) on the subject of argument testing.  There may be a good reasons for the [side-effect method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88861/121) you are using, but in this case a **check** function may simplify things.

```
func::invidx = 
  "Index `1` should be a non-negative machine-sized integer betwwen `2` and `3`.";
func::intnm = "Number `1` should be a non-negative machine-sized integer.";

ClearAll[nni, less, check]
SetAttributes[check, HoldFirst]

nni[n_Integer?NonNegative] := True
nni[else_] := Message[func::intnm, else]

less[i_, n_] /; i <= n || Message[func::invidx, i, 0, n] := True

check[_[n_?nni, i_?nni, x_]] /; less[i, n] := NumericQ[x]
check[_[args___]] /; ! ArgumentCountQ[func, Length[{args}], 3, 3] && False := $Failed;
check[else_] := False
```

And now the main definitions:

```
func[a___]?check := #2/#1*#3 &[a]

func /: Derivative[0, 0, 1][func] := {n, i, x} \[Function] 
  If[Quiet @ check @ Hold[n, i, x],
    n (func[n - 1, i - 1, x] - func[n - 1, i, x]), 
    Quiet @ func[n, i, x]
  ]
```

Now messages are as shown in your example but:

```
D[func[-4, 2, x], x]
```

> func::intnm: Number -4 should be a non-negative machine-sized integer. >>
>
> ```
> func[-4, 2, x]
> ```

```
D[func[-4, 2, x], {x, 2}]
```

> func::intnm: Number -4 should be a non-negative machine-sized integer. >>
>
> ```
> func[-4, 2, x]
> ```

I think this is the result you want?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a question: why `D[func[-4, 2, x], x]` throws many error infos `func::intnm:`, rather than just a `func::intnm:`?

Comment: @Shutao One of them comes from the last term in `If`, which could be avoided with `Defer`.  A `Trace` should show where the others originate; I think I'll do that now.

Comment: @Shutao The other leak came from `check @ Hold[n, i, x]` which I somehow forgot about.  I'll update this answer to give only a single message in that call.

Comment: @Shutao Other than that, now fixed I hope, do you see any other problems in using this?

Comment: @Shutao Oh, I just realized that the `check[_[args___]] /; ! ArgumentCountQ` line isn't doing anything as `check` is only applied to the three-argument form.  I'll fix that too.

Comment: Another issue is`D[func[3, 3, x], x]` cannot work normally:) By your demo, I  know that I just need to add `If[]` to deal with bad argument of `UpValues`

Comment: @Shutao Sorry, it seems I did not take my time with this problem.  I'll try to give it a better go later.